# Unregister Push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I am building an app where we have a login page to authenticate users. When user is authenticated (on successful login) he can receive notifications from our remote server.

I have written the following code in AppDeletegate.m to register Push notifications:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];


    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

The users are receiving Push notifications via APNS and I have no issues with it. My requirement is that when user signs/logs out (It happens on clicking logout button inside our app) I want the Push notifications to be stopped now.

I want the Push notifications to be received on device (iOS device) only when the user has not logged out from my app.

Above the logout signifies just signing off from my app and not uninstalling the app.

Can you help me implementing the above logic?

I am sure other apps must be doing something like that. Take an example of Gmail app, I do not receive any Push notification when I am not logged in inside Gmail app.

Edit:
One possible solution to my issue can be by sending a flag to server regarding the user log out action and store that flag there for that user/device and if that flag is set to ON I will not send the Push notifications from server to APNS to device.

With the above approach what will happen if there is no internet connection on device and user does the logout?

I have the provision to logout  inside the app even if there is no internet. (I am just clearing all the NSUserDefaults there). I am using the following code to log out user:

```
// Reset user defaults
NSUserDefaults * defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary * dict = [defs dictionaryRepresentation];
for (id key in dict) {

        [defs removeObjectForKey:key];

}
[defs synchronize];
```

Is there a way to unsubscribe the Push notifications something like that?

Comment: are you using Parse?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: Are you using Parse.com as your backend?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have your own server to store the push tokens, you can send a request to your server to disable / revoke the push notification for that specific device.

To answer your EDIT part, it is not possible to determine if the user cannot connect to the internet. You may set the logic to only clear the `NSUserDefaults` in a successful logout request callback, or perform a sync-up action when launching the app, etc.